# dynamic qt paths for libs/includes folders in compiled version

Tags: c++, qt, path, compilation, include

I compiled qt 4.8.5 for CentOS 6.4. Everything works perfectly. When I am compiling other libraries using this compiled qt version is compiling as long as I keep the installer folder in the same location. If I move the installer folder in another location, then I get the following errors:

```
cd common/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/path/MashLab/meshlab/src/common'
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DGLEW_STATIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SCRIPT_LIB -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../qt/install_dir/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/path/qt/install/include/QtCore -I/path/qt/install/include/QtGui -I/path/qt/install/include/QtOpenGL -I/path/qt/install/include/QtXml -I/path/qt/install/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/path/qt/install/include/QtScript -I/path/qt/install/include -I../.. -I../../../vcglib -I../external/glew-1.7.0/include -I. -I../external/jhead-2.95 -I/usr/X11R6/inc
lude -I. -o filterparameter.o filterparameter.cpp
filterparameter.cpp:24:18: error: QtCore: No such file or directory
filterparameter.cpp:25:16: error: QMap: No such file or directory
filterparameter.cpp:26:17: error: QPair: No such file or directory
filterparameter.cpp:27:19: error: QAction: No such file or directory
```

It's still searching for the libs and includes in the path where it was installed even if I export the environment variables to the new location:

```
$: export QMAKESPEC=/path/qt/install_dir/mkspecs/linux-g++-64
$: export QTLIB=/path/qt/install_dir/lib
$: export QTINC=/path/qt/install_dir/include
$: export QTDIR=/path/qt/install_dir
```

installed location: /path/qt/install

new location: /path/qt/install_dir

Question: Is there a way (some arguments) which you can compile qt and use dynamic paths of libs/includes?

Answer (score 0):

With Qt >= 5.3 create a qt.conf next to where qmake is (e.g. /path/qt/install_dir/bin/qt.conf)

```
[Paths]
Prefix = ..
```

If this doesn't work, check which at path qmake is looking for qt.conf with

```
strace qmake -query 2>&1 | grep qt.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it doesn't work. When configure it it's taking the absolute path.

Comment: my bad, you said qt 4.8.5, ".." wont worth with that. You'll probably have to resort to putting the absolute path in there:/